# Ist er überhaupt "dessen" Sohn? Ist er überhaupt "sein" Sohn?

Tags: difference, relative-clause, demonstrative-pronoun

This sentence has me baffled. I know that dessen is used in relative clauses, but in this sentence

> Ist er überhaupt dessen Sohn

what I see with "his son" is a demostrative, not a relative clause.

Why the use of "dessen" then?

Answer (score 3):

In German *dessen* can occur as a relative pronoun or a **demonstrative pronoun**. Here the latter is the case. *Dessen* places way more emphasis on the father, as is expected for a demonstrative pronoun. „Is he that one’s son, anyway“, as opposed to „is he his son, anyway. Such constructions often aid clarity, because:

> In the sentence „ist er überhaupt sein Sohn“ we don’t know whether the doubt concerns the identity as a son, or the identity as a father.

Compare the following case:

> Ist er überhaupt sein Sohn? Ich dachte er sei sein Enkel!

The same can occur with *dessen*, but is extremely unlikely, because *dessen* as a demonstrative pronoun tends to receive considerable stress or at least attention. The emphasis need not always be mirrored in very audible verbal stress. It can refer back to something for clarity:

> Rainer sagt er kenne einen Fußballtrainer und dessen Sohn sei Profifußballer/Rainer said he knew a soccer coach and said coach’s son was a professional soccer player.

Here it is the coach who has fathered a professional soccer player. If I were to say:

> Rainer sagt er kenne einen Fußballtrainer und sein Sohn sei Profifußballer/Rainer said he knew a soccer coach and his son was a professional soccer player.

I would by default assume Rainer himself to be the father of the soccer player. Hence *dessen* can fulfil a role similar to *that...‘s*, „said ...‘s“ in English. **These are merely examples. Relative clauses would be  both  elegant and unambiguous**.

Comment: So then the only difference is where the emphasis is applied? With "dessen" is on the father, with "sein" the child?

Comment: @EnriqueMorenoTent Emphasis and loss of ambiguity. See edit, please.